# How often are packages updated in Lucid?

Tags: 10.04, updates

I'm using Ubuntu since Dapper and I really love it. Right now, I have three production machines running Lucid with some PPAs. And I don't like this scenario since PPAs apps usually make badly-made packages (not respecting debian standards).

I wonder how often packages hits the repository in Lucid? Can we expect to see changes in universe repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updates in released versions of Ubuntu are for security and bug fixes only. Generally speaking you won't see new releases of things hit the archive, except in certain cases like Firefox.

The [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) wiki page explains this process.

There is a section of the archive called [Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) where newer versions of software are backported to the older releases, this might be a good "middle ground" for you if you want newer packages of something.

These packages are based on versions of the packages in a newer Ubuntu release so if you have trust/quality issues with a PPA then that might work for you.